# Can someone please explain to me

Tags: python, operators

.. the difference between the = and the == signs in Python? i.e provide examples when each is used so there's no confusion between the two?

Comment: Fortunately, you can't mix up the two in Python (like you can in C-family languages). Using the wrong one in the wrong place in Python is a syntax error.

Comment: actually, you _can_ mix them up while calling functions. a=b provides a keyword parameter named 'a', while a==b provides a positional parameter.

Comment: Was the Python documentation site down?  What tutorial are you using?

Comment: @Marco Mariani: Good point, I had forgotten that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is assignment, `==` is equality.

```
a = 5  # assigns the variable a to 5
a == 5 # returns true
a == 4 # returns false
a = 4 # a is now 4
a == 4 # returns true
```

Answer (score 3):

= is used to assign variables ie `number = 30` - the "number" variable now holds the number 30.

== is used as a boolean operator to check whether variables are equal to each other ie `1 == 1` would give `true` and `1 == 2` would return `false`

Comment: So == is only used in evaluating whether something is true or not and not for any other case?

Answer (score 0):

`=` is assignment, you would use it to give a value to a variable.

`str = "hello"` assigns "hello" to `str`, so that if you were to get the value of `str`, it would be a `hello`.

`==` is equality comparison, you use it to compare two values.

```
if str == "hello": 
   print "equal"
else:
   print "not equal"
```

In that code you want to see if the value of `str` is equal to the string "hello", and if we assigned it as above, this would result in "equal" being printed.

Answer (score 0):

"==" is checking for equality. "=" is for assignment of values. eg `v="100"` Then to check whether `v` is 100, `v==100`